# How to create & group OR LIKE query with multiple columns in Yii2?

Tags: mysql, sql, yii2

How I can create query in Yii2 like this with query builder?

```
SELECT * 
FROM blog 
WHERE status = 1 AND (
    author_username LIKE '%Steve%' 
    OR author_first_name LIKE '%Steve%' 
    OR author_last_name LIKE '%Steve%'
)
```

I'm trying to find right way to use it in the search model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this query:

1. Using `PDO`:

   ```
   $q='Stev';
   Yii::$app->db->createCommand('
       SELECT * 
       FROM blog 
       WHERE status = 1 AND (
           author_username LIKE :Q 
           OR author_first_name LIKE :Q 
           OR author_last_name LIKE :Q
       )
       ',['Q'=>"%$q%"])
       ->queryAll();
   ```
2. Using `yii\db\Query`:

   ```
   $condition = [
       'OR',                               //Operand (C1 OR C2)
       [                                   //Condition1 (C1) which is complex
           'OR',                           //Operand (C1.1 OR C1.2)
           ['like','author_username',$q],  //C1.1
           ['like','author_first_name',$q] //C1.2
       ],
       ['like','author_last_name',$q]      //Condition2(C2)
   ];

   (new yii\db\Query())
       ->from('blog')
       ->andWhere('status = 1')
       ->andWhere($condition)
       ->all();
   ```
3. Using `ActiveRecord (ActiveQuery)`:

   ```
   Blog::find()
   ->active()
   ->andWhere($condition)
   ->all();
   ```

you can test your query using `QueryBuilder`:

```
var_dump(Yii::$app->db->queryBuilder->build($your_query));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! 2nd variant is best for me :)

Answer (score 0):

In yii2 you can use Yii::$app->db->createCommand to run your mysql query.

**1. For SELECT operation:**

1.1 Get all records:

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand($mysqlquery)->queryAll();
```

1.2 Get Single record

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand($mysqlquery)->queryOne();
```

**2. For UPDATE/DELETE**

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand($mysqlquery)->execute();
```